# How to create a list using the wget utility?

Tags: command-line, wget

I need to use the `wget` utility correctly. I want to download content from certain links into one file and so that the result is saved in a list, and not in one row *(that is, in one line)*

For example, if I run these two commands at the same time, the result is saved in one row.

```
wget -qO- https://pastebin.com/raw/AsGwULK7
wget -qO- https://pastebin.com/raw/RkkRkak3
```

What checkbox do I need to add to indent each downloaded data? *(By indentation I assume* `"\ n"` *Mode)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ wget -qO- https://pastebin.com/raw/AsGwULK7
printf '\n'
wget -qO- https://pastebin.com/raw/RkkRkak3; } >file
```